# Time difference of time string (only want the calculate the difference of the minutes then convert to seconds)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have 2 times a start and finish time (lasttime), in the format of (HH:MM:SS). I need to find the difference between in time between the minutes (converted in seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your columns that are string, please use the code below

```
from datetime import timedelta
df['diffT']=(pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime_str'], format='%H:%M:%S')-pd.to_datetime(df['LastTime_str'], format='%H:%M:%S'))//timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: Could you explain more why I would use timedelta? at the moment your code does not come up with exactly what i need which is just the difference between the Minutes (in seconds) thank you

Comment: datetime objects cannot be subtracted directly from each other, hence timedelta is needed. For me when i use your data, i get the difference in minutes perfectly. with `(pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime_str'], format='%H:%M:%S')` we are converting the column into Datetime object & then doing subtraction action on it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this is there way I can work out is the difference of the StartTime at index 2 (e.g 00:07:05) and LastTime at index 3 (00:02:05) etc and keep working this out while going down the column something like this? `UDP_interval['diffT']=(pd.to_datetime(UDP_interval.iloc[[2 ,0 ] , : ], format='%H:%M:%S')-pd.to_datetime(UDP_interval.iloc[[1 ,0 ] , : ], format='%H:%M:%S'))//timedelta(minutes=60) `

Comment: try this & see if this is what you want `df['diffT']=(pd.to_datetime(df['LastTime'].shift(-1), format='%H:%M:%S')-pd.to_datetime(df['StartTime'], format='%H:%M:%S'))//timedelta(seconds=1)` The only change from before is `shift(-1)`. You can tinker with the value inside shift to get the result you want

Answer (score 0):

### Data:

```
StartTime,LastTime
00:02:05,00:03:05
00:02:05,00:05:05
00:07:05,00:10:05
00:07:05,00:15:05
00:12:06,00:30:06
00:12:06,00:35:06
```

### Create `DataFrame`:

#### from clipboard:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

#### from csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv('UDP_interval.csv', delim_whitespace=True, usecols=['StartTime','LastTime'])
```

#### `df`:

[image]

#### `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 2 columns):
StartTime    6 non-null object
LastTime     6 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```

### Function:

```
def seconds_between(x):
    time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
    t1 = datetime.strptime(x[0], time_format)
    t2 = datetime.strptime(x[1], time_format)
    return abs((t2 - t1).seconds)
```

### Apply function:

```
df['Diff_sec'] = df.apply(seconds_between, axis=1)
```

### Final:

[image]

Comment: This is similar to my approach and I know this works with your data but not with my data ...I just get the error dtype: object' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' and ValueError: time data '0

Comment: My dataframe came from a csv file which is why i used  UDP_interval = pd.read_csv('UDP_interval.csv', delim_whitespace=True, usecols=['StartTime','LastTime']) and separated by whitespace. So I am not sure why I would use df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

Comment: @Tina you don't, that's just for reading in the data at the top of my solution